# Calculate time for each step of a shell script and show total execution time

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have below script and for a requirement I have to place some function for each of these script to get time information for each script and at last show total time.

My main scripts looks like below:

```
/u01/scripts/stop.sh ${1} | tee ${stop_log}    
/u01/scripts/kill_proc.sh ${1} | tee ${kill_log}    
/u01/scripts/detach.sh ${1}| tee ${detach_log}   
/u01/scripts/copy.sh ${1} | tee ${copy_log}
```

I want to use something like below function to get every script execution time and at last with a global variable I can show Total time taken by all the scripts.

I created below but unfortunately I could not use properly , if you have something kindly help here.

```
time_check()    
{         
  export time_log=${log}/time_log_${dts}.log          
  echo 'StartingTime:'date +%s > ${time_log}       
  echo 'EndingTime:'date +%s >> ${time_log}           
}
```

I want to use something like above function to get every script execution time and at last with a global variable I can show total time taken by all the scripts .  Could anyone please guide how to get the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are OK with the time granularity of seconds, you could simply do this:

```
start=$SECONDS
/u01/scripts/stop.sh ${1} | tee ${stop_log}
stop=$SECONDS   
/u01/scripts/kill_proc.sh ${1} | tee ${kill_log}
kill_proc=$SECONDS   
/u01/scripts/detach.sh ${1}| tee ${detach_log}
detach=$SECONDS  
/u01/scripts/copy.sh ${1} | tee ${copy_log}
end=$SECONDS

printf "%s\n" "stop=$((stop-start)), kill_proc=$((kill_proc-stop)), detach=$((detach-kill_proc)), copy=$((end-detach)), total=$((end-start))"
```

You can write a function to do this as well:

```
time_it() {
  local start=$SECONDS rc
  echo "$(date): Starting $*"
  "$@"; rc=$?
  echo "$(date): Finished $*; elapsed = $((SECONDS-start)) seconds"
  return $rc
}
```

With Bash version >= 4.2 you can use `printf` to print date rather than invoking an external command:

```
time_it() {
  local start=$SECONDS ts rc
  printf -v ts '%(%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S)T' -1
  printf '%s\n' "$ts Starting $*"
  "$@"; rc=$?
  printf -v ts '%(%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S)T' -1
  printf '%s\n' "$ts Finished $*; elapsed = $((SECONDS-start)) seconds"
  return $rc
}
```

And invoke it as:

```
start=$SECONDS
time_it /u01/scripts/stop.sh ${1} | tee ${stop_log}    
time_it /u01/scripts/kill_proc.sh ${1} | tee ${kill_log}    
time_it /u01/scripts/detach.sh ${1}| tee ${detach_log}   
time_it /u01/scripts/copy.sh ${1} | tee ${copy_log}
echo "Total time = $((SECONDS-start)) seconds"
```

---

Related:

- [How do I measure duration in seconds in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5152858/6862601)

Comment: Thanks for your quick suggestion. I will check your approach. Also if any function we can place that is main requirement . In function if we can put any global variable that can be used to show the result at last .

Comment: Great . Thanks for the help , it seems it will fulfill my requirement . I will check this and update further. Thanks,

Comment: Hi , I just tried the function . I got something like below for printf   line 23: printf: `(': invalid format character

Comment: Check your bash version.  Use the first function if you have < 4.2 version.

Comment: Acknowledged . I have lower version version 4.1.2(2)-release

Comment: I have a doubt , if scripts failed in some stage say in detach.sh , I have to start it next phase say copy.sh then in that case how this will calculate ? shouldn't we have a global variable to call that and preserve the time till detach phase .  Please advise me if we can do something like that .

Comment: Calculation will work regardless of if the timed command fails or not.  You need additional logic if you want special treatment for failures.

Comment: Please guide how to handle failures , failures are bound to happen.

Comment: That’s a separate question

Comment: Ok , understood . This function working fine for me but it is not supporting incase of failure in any steps . I will create another question. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I modified the function so that it does return the exit code of the command it runs.